# Why would this XML cause "there are multiple root elements" error?

Tags: xml, api

Processing EXE is reporting "System.Xml.XmlException: There are multiple root elements. Line 2, position 2."

The XML returned looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api><response status="ok"><token>6a4a4dfe610572668167a67c3a0fa815</token></response></api>
```

The EXE is a black box to us and we have no support or documentation to go on.  We are recreating an API by emulating its responses.  My XML looks exactly like old API's XML and response is preceded by `<?php header('Content-type: text/xml'); ?>`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that xml.

Comment: @Nix is right - the problem should be in the code that reads the XML. maybe this will help: http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/reading-xml-document-fragments-in-net/

Comment: Thanks guys.  Confirmation of what I thought.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the XML, so check the calling code.

If you post it we can help you out.

Comment: I agree.  The binary is a black box to us and I would not be allowed to post it even if someone could decompile it.  Thanks though!

Comment: Still struggling on blindly on this.  A Windows pro suggested that the .NET XML parser might be having trouble with whitespace?  In this case it would be the newline after <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>.  Ever heard of this being an issue?  I'm no .NET guy...

Comment: I have heard of the opposite, if there is a new line before DOC-TYPE I have seen it complain.

Comment: Thanks Nix.  Found issue and added an answer below.  Leaving yours as correct answer.  Appreciate your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this as an answer but leaving Nix's answer as the selected correct answer to hopefully help someone else with this dilemma.

I was assigning value of auth token in PHP like so:

```
$string = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$string .= time();
$auth = md5($string);
```

In some way this line `$string = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];` was causing the .NET XML parser to perceive whitespace or a newline that could not be seen when looking at the XML output but commenting out that line got rid of the “there are multiple root elements” error.

Thanks to all who looked at this!